# Local sub-domains on httpd apache

Tags: apache, url, wampserver

I have on my machine wampp server installed that I use to run php applications.

There are many folder in the htdocs with inside my projects and I can see those in the browser at this url: localhost/folder-name/.

I'd like to see every project in a custom url like: dev.name-folder.com

With IIS is very easy to do that, can someone explain how do that with Apache, using wampp server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to map domain names like dev.name-folder.com to your local system. (Otherwise you'll have to use a DNS server).

To configure a vhost in apache create a file for each domain/project you'd like to serve:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@domain.tld
    ServerName domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/domain.tld/html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/htdocs/domain.tld/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ServerName is the domain name you'd like to serve your files under. DocumentRoot must be set to the absolute path to your files (here taken from a linux system).

Comment: Yep, hosts file editing is the only way to go if you don't run your own DNS.

Comment: Then you need to configure apache to map that domain to your local file path.

Comment: where? How? I'm not an expert of wampp... usually I work on IIS and asp.net, not php and Apache...

Comment: What now XAMPP or WAMP? These are two different packages. Search for the apache2.conf in your <whatever>-AMPP directory. There should be some hint to where your *AMPP stores the vhost confs.